# XML error while invoking an API in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-asynctask, http-post

"There is an error in XML document (7,26)". This is the response I am getting from a web API. I checked Manifest.xml and every other XML file in the project but nothing unusual there. The API request isn't sent through XML but in the Main Activity using Async Task. If the question requires codes and background of project then do tell me I will edit my post. Thanks in Advance to everyone.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.abdullahazam.myapplication"  >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/pitb"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The above code is as mentioned is manifest.xml. The below one is mainactivity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#00a651" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

Comment: mainactivity.xml's first 7 lines

Comment: what error shows on logcat?

Comment: It doesn't show any error. However the response from the API tells there is an error. This is what exactly response string is {"success":"109","message":"There is an error in XML document (7, 26)."}
Where success means that the security key is valid and successfully invoked the API. 109 means "Exception: system has encountered an unexpected error" and the message of 109 error code is "There is an error in XML document (7, 26)."

Comment: remove   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"  in mainactivity then try

Comment: no success. The same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the parameters. API server couldn't identify one of the parameters format and was returning such unidentified error. So this case was particularly with my Application and API server.